# Charge 20 V batteries with USB-PD

Tags: usb-pd

A number of power tools now use 20V or so batteries (ex. Milwaukee, Bosch, DeWalt, Parkside, etc). All of them usually come with their own charger (I think only DeWalt has the USB-C port directly on the batteries).

I wonder what kind of circuitry is necessary to create a charger from USB-C (USB-PD) source for these?

EDIT:

I just found about the ZY12PDN chip. What would I need in addition to build a Li-ion battery charger around it?

Comment: Constant current limiting, cut off current and BMS negotiation to name a few.

Comment: I think you are starting the project from the wrong end. You first need to reverse-engineer the custom interfaces between battery and charger. Only then when you know how to communicate and charge the batteries, you may begin to think what kind of circuitry should be used to communicate and charge the batteries.

Comment: Would there be some ready made OTS circuitry i could just append to the ZY12PDN to add cut off, current limiting and charge detection? I found https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BKSnIXnL9M but i'm not 100% sure what i'm looking at.. It seems one of those buck/boost modules that only changes output voltage/current

Comment: @Pa_ Again your target is to charge unknown proprietary batteries somehow. The next problem is to have a charger that takes in 20V and charges the unknown proprietary batteries. Getting a 20V supply from any source, such as from USB-PD, is the final and most simplest part of the project.

Comment: @Justme thanks, a bit clearer. Would it make a difference if i was going to build the battery myself by choosing the cells, but keeping their battery electronics? or is there no easy way around to their charger? From my understanding Li-ion batteries usually need to be charged at a specific but somewhat standard voltage, and the charge must stop when the voltage of the battery reaches a given level (possibly after lowering the amps in the last bit of the charge)? In the specific case, these powertools batteries are usually made of a fixed number of 18650 cells (5?) to reach the label 20V

Comment: @Pa_ yes, whether you build the battery from cells yourself or buy a tool battery makes a difference. Tool batteries typically contain a part of the charging electronics themselves, or at least a protector that won't let them charge if the other end doesn't correctly identify itself as the matching (typically: same company) charger. It's mostly a method for tool vendors to ensure they also sell the batteries and the chargers, but there's a reasonable amount of caution in there (as lithium batteries can burn nastily if people buy nice high-capacity Bosch batteries and use a bad 5€ charger).

Comment: @Pa_ but even without vendor lock-in circuitry, it's not trivial how to charge 5 batteries in series. Do you disconnect the series and charge them individually? Do you bring out pins to control balancing circuitry? What about temperature sensing – how do you connect 5 thermo sensors, or do you mechanically make sure that the one sensor is thermally coupled to all the cells? What sensor do you use?

Comment: @Justme I think usually the "custom interface between battery and charger" is just a direct (via protection chip) connection to the battery, and a temperature sensor attached to the battery. The arrangement of connections can be different on different brands.

Comment: @user253751 You seem to be forgetting the battery management and authentication. Days of the battery pack being just a dumb container for cells and providing charging terminals are long gone. Like laptop batteries, these can communicate with the charger and powered device.

Comment: @Justme Laptop batteries may have right-to-disrepair nonsense in them, but power tool batteries mostly don't.

Comment: @user253751 Then why do people ask here how to reverse-engineer power tool battery communication protocols here? All the major brands have their custom design and don't want their brand getting degraded by letting someone else manufacture poor quality and dangerous replacement batteries or chargers for their products. People are so cheap they are willing to sacrifice safety by buying dangerous off-brand batteries and chargers.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thans for pointing out these very interesting aspects. Then, i wonder: is there any open design for these kind of batteries, so that i can just use the shell of a stock battery but chose the cells and the rest of the electronics myself and charge it accordingly?

Comment: I mean, i suppose there should be a number of designs to draw 20V from USB-PD to charge 20V li-ion battery packs?

Comment: So i found the project for using the circuitry and chassis of an original Parkside battery and then replace the cells and double the amount to turn it into a 4Ah battery. Then i thought: couldn't it be possible to split the circuitry from the cells, create a physical coupler somehow, and turn that "dumb" cell assembly + pinout into the actual battery to be charged in any way one wants (even tru the offy charger, when coupled with the "head")?